# Cakephp - contain (containable behavior) fetches too much

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, containable

As I understood from the cakephp-documentation, one of the advantages of the 'containable'-Behavior is being able to fetch fewer data if you need fewer data...

But that doesn't seem to work in my case of a connection between users and usergroups.

My associations look like:

```
    Group
    hasMany: Membership

    User
    hasMany: Membership

    Membership
    belongsTo: User, Group
```

(I'm not using HABTM, instead use the Model 'Membership' in between to join users and groups).

All Models implement the 'Containable'-Behavior.

Now I want to get all the members of a group with a certain id, only their ids and mail-addresses. My query is built like that:

```
    $members = $this->Membership->find('all', array(
        'conditions'    => array(
                'group_id'      => $id
            ),
        'contain'       => array(
            'User'          => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'fullName')
            ),
        )
    ));
```

But the resulting array looks like:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
            'Membership' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'group_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'role' => 'member'
        ),
        'Group' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Foo Group'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'password' => '*****',
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Dr. Foo'
            'mail' => 'foo@bar.baz',
            'role' => 'admin'
        )
    )
)
```

So there are definietely more fields fetched than I wanted to... (it's the same thing btw wenn I set the 'contain'-key to:

```
    'contain'   => array(
        'User.fullName', 'User.id'
    )
```

Am I using the containable-behavior wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your models don't seem to be acting containabl-y at all. Have you set your models to act as containable?

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

If so, maybe the problem is with the recursion (to avoid getting the `Group` array with the query). Containable behavior should handle the recursion level on its own, but try setting it on the AppModel just to be sure

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $recursive = -1;
```

Your first attempt

```
    'contain'       => array(
        'User'          => array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'fullName')
        ),
    )
```

looks good in terms of syntax, so it probably the `actAs` thing.

Also, for debugging also, try

```
$this->Membership->contain('User');
$this->Membership->find('all', array(
    'conditions'    => array(
            'group_id'      => $id
        ));
```

and see if you get the expected results that way.

Comment: The $actsAs-thing was it indeed, thank you. My AppModel had:
public $actAs = array('Containable'), not $act**s**As... Stupid typo, stupid me... ;-)