# Model Association Not Correct

Tags: cakephp

I am few months old with CakePHP. This is first time I am trying CakePhp Association. I assume I am following almost all instruction but still my model doesn't seem to work.

This is simple 'User' and 'Profile' Model. Table Structure: User:
- id (Primary Key)
- name

Profile:
- id (primary key)
- role
- user_id (Reference Key)

Models: User:

```
class UserModel extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'User';
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Profile'
    );

}
```

Profile:

```
class ProfileModel extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'Profile';
    public $belongsTo = array('User'); }
```

Controller: Users:

```
lass UsersController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'Users';
    public $scaffold;

    function index(){
        $user = $this->User->find('all'); //HERE I expect to get User and Profiles data
        pr($user);
    }

}
```

Profiles:

```
 class ProfilesController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'Profiles';
    public $scaffold;

    function index(){
        $profile = $this->Profile->find('all');
        pr($profile);
    }

}
```

If I run users: /localhost/test_php_apps/users/ I get:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => rohini
                )

        )

)
```

I am wondering why 'Profile' data is not shown. I have manually added records in tables.

Further if I try in UsersController:  `$user = $this->User->Profile->find('all');` I get the following error:

> Call to a member function find() on a non-object

My guess is something is wrong with setting up Associations. But not sure what is messing things up.

I know this is very basic question, but even after reading 10 to 15 related cases I don't seem to find the answer.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any containable action going on here. What is you `$recursive` value?

Comment: I have set it:class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actAs = 'Containable';
}

Comment: don't use Containable. this is pretty simple. when you get "Call to a member function find() on a non-object" means your model is not associated. Containable used for other purpose

Answer (score 0):

Do me a favor, change

```
class UserModel extends AppModel
```

to

```
class User extends AppModel
```

and

```
class ProfileModel extends AppModel
```

to

```
class Profile extends AppModel
```

and see if that helps when doing `$user = $this->User->Profile->find('all');` in the UsersController.

Also, is

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

not

```
public $actAs = 'Containable';
```

not `actAs`. See if that helps any. If not, it would be helpful to know your cake version.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724491/cakephp-contain-containable-behavior-fetches-too-much/18725242#18725242) for containable and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404345/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-newsmodel/19404521#19404521) for naming model conventions.

Comment: I did as you said, but it is not working. My cake version is 2.4.

Comment: Did it at least change the error from `Call to a member function find() on a non-object` to something else?

Comment: If you set your containable, then add the `'contain' => array('Profile')` option to your `find()` call

Comment: No error stays the same. I did change it like:  
        $user = $this->User->Profile->find('all',array('contain' => array('Profile') )); //Not sure is this correct way.

Comment: Try it without profile, but containing it: `$user = $this->User->find('all',array('contain' => array('Profile') ));`

Comment: is there any configuration required for CakePhp Association to work

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines in your usermodel

```
public $useTable = 'YOUR USERTABLENAME';
```

and change

```
public $hasOne = array(
        'Profile'
    );
```

to `public $hasOne = 'Profile';`

in your profilmodel add the same.

```
public $useTable = 'YOUR PROFILETABLENAME';
```

and change

```
public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

to

```
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User',
                                          'foreignKey' => 'user_id'));
```

in your userscontontroller add this

```
public $uses = array('User','Profile');
```

normally it should work now when you try the query

```
$u = $this->User->find('all',array('contain' => array('Profile'));
```

or

```
$u = $this->User->find('all',array('recursive' => 2));
```

but it also should work if you write only:

```
$u $this->User->find('all');
```

regards

Comment: Didn't work, not sure when actually is wrong. It is quite simple but unfortunately not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you bake this things is made your life easier.

Models: User:

```
    class User extends AppModel{
        var $name = 'User';
        public $hasMany = array(
            'Profile'=>array(
                'className' => 'Profile',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',)
        );    
}
```

Profile:

```
class Profile extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'Profile';
            public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        )
    );
```

}

Controller: Users:

```
    class UsersController extends AppController{
        var $name = 'User';        

        public function index(){
            $users = $this->User->find('all'); 
            var_dump($users);
        }

}
```

Controller Profile:

```
    class ProfilesController extends AppController{
            var $name = 'Profile';        

            public function index(){
                $user_id = 2;
                $users = $this->Profile->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Profile.user_id'=>$user_id))); 
                var_dump($users);
            }

    }
```

Comment: I tried this one but still no luck. I expect sql query to use some join. Presently query looks like: <br> SELECT `Profile`.`id`, `Profile`.`role`, `Profile`.`user_id` FROM `test`.`profiles` AS `Profile` WHERE `Profile`.`user_id` = 1

Comment: Just wanted to add my sql queries, not sure what is wrong,                     CREATE TABLE users (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(60));
CREATE TABLE profiles (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, role varchar(60), user_id INT, CONSTRAINT fk_usr_profile FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES test.users(id));

Comment: I see.. your database is not configured properly. or your saving statement in your controller is incorrect. If you have it live let me check it for you

Comment: I am using WAMP - MySql, I can insert data manually, so there is no issue. Even I know there is some issue with database, cannot show you live as I am working on localhost. Any inputs on database step would be really helpful.

Comment: Further if use $this->User->query("SELECT users.* , profiles.* from users INNER JOIN profiles ON users.id = profiles.user_id"); then it gives me expected result:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => david
                )

            [profiles] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [role] => admin
                    [user_id] => 1
                )
        )   

)

Comment: can you show me your save view and method in controller. sounds you trying to save id of NULL - I also added public to method try that

Comment: I have not added any 'save' method. As you would be aware in 'phpmyadmin' interface allows to insert data in tables directly. So in this case I have already inserted data in tables and there is ligitimate data in tables. That is reason why query() is working fine.

Comment: Any further comments, not able to fix it yet

Comment: if you have it live let me look at it.

Comment: how to make it live, any suggestions

Comment: I retried as per the tutorial, http://blog.the-nerd.be/2012/08/cakephp-basics-tutorial-part-4/. Things are working fine. User Profile Example